# QFileDialog.getOpenFileName has no keyword argument `selectedFilter`

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, python-3.5

Using Python 3.5 and PyQt 4.12 (compiled from source). I just realized that `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName` has no keyword argument `selectedFilter`:

```
Help on built-in function getOpenFileName:

getOpenFileName(...)
    getOpenFileName(parent: QWidget = None, caption: str = '', directory: str = '', filter: str = '', options: Union[QFileDialog.Options, QFileDialog.Option] = 0) -> str
```

[The documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName) mentions both signatures with and without `selectedFilter` but does not mention Python 3 as a special case.

I crosschecked with Python 2.7 (built PyQt4 from the same source) and `selectedFilter` is present here:

```
Help on built-in function getOpenFileName:

getOpenFileName(...)
    getOpenFileName(parent: QWidget = None, caption: str = '', directory: str = '', filter: str = '', selectedFilter: str = '', options: QFileDialog.Options = 0) -> str
```

Does anyone know why there is this difference in PyQt4 when using Python 3?

(By the way in PyQt5 the same method has a consistent signature for Python 2.7 and Python 3.5).

Comment: Is the `selectedFilter` missing when you actually use the function, or is it only missing in the documentation?

Comment: @titusjan It's not only missing in the documentation, I get a `TypeError: getOpenFileName(parent: QWidget = None, caption: str = '', directory: str = '', filter: str = '', options: Union[QFileDialog.Options, QFileDialog.Option] = 0): 'selectedFilter' is not a valid keyword argument` when I use it.